# Install Ubuntu on Windows 8.1

Tags: installation, windows

Can I install Ubuntu on a **Windows 8.1 computer**? That computer is the one I currently use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But it all depends on your Hardware, (for example Touchpad drivers or other things may still be buggy, and you need to search a little for solutions)

1. That kind of computer do you have for example  HP envy 12345
2. Do you want to have still your Windows booting, or do you want to remove Windows completly.

Answer (score 0):

If your Desktop or Desktop came with pre-installed Windows 8 or 8.1 you can use this

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)